# Can not get the file names with convmv

Tags: freebsd, filenames, character-encoding

I have just uploaded some files on a FreeBSD server. Some files have the `???` into their names. The files came from a windows machine, so I try this:

```
$ convmv -f cp850 -t utf-8 *
Starting a dry run without changes...
mv "./??-145x145.jpg"   "./íª-145x145.jpg"
mv "./??-150x104.jpg"   "./íª-150x104.jpg"
mv "./??-150x150.jpg"   "./íª-150x150.jpg"
mv "./??-220x145.jpg"   "./íª-220x145.jpg"
mv "./??-225x145.jpg"   "./íª-225x145.jpg"
mv "./??-380x245.jpg"   "./íª-380x245.jpg"
mv "./??-570x396.jpg"   "./íª-570x396.jpg"
```

`convmv` finds the files, however I still can not get the name when trying to change the encoding to utf-8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--notest`:

```
convmv --notest -f cp850 -t utf-8 ./*
```

From [convmv manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=convmv&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html):

```
--notest
       Needed to actually rename the files. By default convmv will just
       print what it wants to do.
```

Comment: the problem is that the output is wrong

Comment: What happen when using `-f windows-1255`?